# How to monitor STDERR in Java?

Tags: java, monitor, stderr

We are integrating with a 3rd party API and have purchased the license to use their Java library (wraps the API calls in object oriented fashion).

The only problem with this Java lib is that it doesn't throw exceptions or faults if the API calls fail. The only indication we get from the client-side is output to either STDOUT (on success) or STDERR (on fail).

Hence, running:

```
try {
    com.the.third.party.java.lib.FizzBuzz.doSomething();
} catch(Throwable t) {
    log.error(t);
}
```

...never *catches* anything. If an error occurs while `doSomething()` is running, we'll simply see the following String printed to STDERR:

```
Error: <details of the error here>
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to *monitor* STDERR (`System.err`) for any output that contains the substring "`Error:`"? This could get somewhat complicated due to stream buffering, so I'm not sure what the correct approach should be.

Answer (score 2):

First, if there's another way to detect errors that doesn't involve doing this, do that instead. Your future self will thank you.

But if you really need to listen to `System.err`, you might want to use `System.setErr(PrintStream)`. Write your own PrintStream subclass that looks for "Error:" in the text being printed.

Comment: Thanks @immibus (+1) - I assume I should probably save off the existing `System.err` *prior* to calling `FizzBuzz.doSomething()`, and then swap it back in place of my custom `PrintStream` *after* the method executes (to keep the rest of the app correctly directing STDERR traffic? **Also, more importantly, what might this custom `PrintStream` look like?** Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately I too had to do something like this recently;  I came across the following library which redirects sysout and err to slf4j.  It can be used as an example to follow.  https://github.com/Mahoney/sysout-over-slf4j.